# How to determine whether a multi-column index exists

Tags: mysql, indexing

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127156/how-do-i-check-if-index-exists-on-a-table-field-in-mysql) what I want to do is determine if an index exists, however using more than one column. For example, I have the following table for a hotel room:

```
CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
 `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `res_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `room_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `adults` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `children` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `young_children` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `pets` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `smoking` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `room_id` (`room_id`,`date`),
 KEY `res_num` (`res_num`),
 KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=97449 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I want to add a single index on `room_id` and `date` only if it does not exist already. Doing `SHOW INDEX` produces the following output:

```
mysql> show index from rooms;
+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| rooms |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id          | A         |       67399 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          0 | room_id   |            1 | room_id     | A         |          58 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          0 | room_id   |            2 | date        | A         |       67399 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | res_num   |            1 | res_num     | A         |       67399 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rooms |          1 | date      |            1 | date        | A         |        6739 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I could also limit the output only to the columns in question by doing:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM rooms WHERE Column_name = 'room_id' OR Column_name = 'date';
```

However the individual columns may have their own index, like the `date` column in the case above. How can I determine that an index exists on multiple columns that all belonging to the same `Key_name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TimSparrow's answer really pointed me in the right direction here, so be sure to upvote his answer too. Here's how you can do it all in one step without relying on any external programming languages:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'rooms'
AND index_name = (
    SELECT index_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'rooms'
    AND Seq_in_index = 2 
    AND Column_name IN ("room_id", "date")
)
AND Column_name IN ("room_id", "date")
```

Just put all of your columns that the index contains in the `Column_name` part and change `Seq_in_index` to be the number of columns in the index. If it returns the same value as `Seq_in_index`, the index exists.

You can also easily extend this to indexes using more than 2 columns. For example, the following will return `5` if the index exists using all of those columns:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'rooms'
AND index_name = (
    SELECT index_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'rooms'
    AND Seq_in_index = 5
    AND Column_name IN ("room_id", "date", "foo", "bar", "baz")
)
AND Column_name IN ("room_id", "date", "foo", "bar", "baz")
```

Comment: Great! I will have to think of a way how to make it a function, like hasIndex(Array), for queryBuilder style approach

Comment: And I do not think there is a way to optimize this query - complexity stays the same

Comment: @TimSparrow I agree, this would be better as a function.

Answer (score 2):

First, issue command like

```
SHOW INDEX FROM rooms
WHERE Seq_in_index > 1 
AND Column_name IN ("id", "date")
```

You will get a list of indexes based on more than one column and containing at least one of the columns you need. From the list of results, you take Key_name and then repeat the query for each result:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM rooms WHERE Key_name=?
```

If you get two rows in the results and both columns you need are in the list, then your index exists.

If anyone knows how to do this in pure SQL without relying on external programming language, or suggest a more optimal approach, please improve the answer

Comment: I think I got it figured out. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can check multiple columns indexed with the following statement, assumed you don't want check multiple columns as primary-keys indexed

```
select  table_schema, table_name, index_name, group_concat(column_name) column_name
from    information_schema.statistics
where   table_schema = 'your_schema'
and     index_name != 'PRIMARY'
group by table_schema, table_name, index_name
having count(column_name) > 1
```