# Check if a unique index key exists in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The [Schema\Builder](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html) class has a `hasTable()` and `hasColumn()` methods to check the existence of a table and a column, respectively.

Is there any method or way to check if an index key (such as a unique key) exists?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While Laravel doesn't provide any method to check the existence of a key, you could use any [of the available queries in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127156/908174) and then use `DB::select()`.

For instance:

```
$keyExists = DB::select(
    DB::raw(
        'SHOW KEYS
        FROM your_table_name
        WHERE Key_name=\'your_key_name\''
    )
);
```

Just replace `your_table_name` and `your_key_name` for the correct values.

Comment: Laravel uses Doctrine in spots (especially Schema), so `doctrine/dbal`'s `listTableIndexes()` might be a better solution than a `DB::raw` call that's MySQL-specific. http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html

Comment: @ceejayoz To get the Doctrine Manager in Laravel: `$conn = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()`

Comment: @ceejayoz link no longer exists [https://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html]

Comment: I think that it's not working anymore, I'm getting an exception: `PDO::prepare(): Argument #1 ($query) must be of t
ype string, Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression given`

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Laravel then most likely you will have access to an ORM like Eloquent. Assuming you are using Eloquent, you might be able to do something like this:

```
try {
    Schema::table(
        'the_name_of_your_table',
        function (Blueprint $table) {
            $sm = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager();
            $indexesFound = $sm->listTableIndexes('the_name_of_your_table');

            $indexesToCheck = [
                'index_name_1',
                'index_name_2',
                'index_name_3',
                'index_name_4'
            ];

            foreach ($indexesToCheck as $currentIndex) {
                if (array_key_exists($currentIndex, $indexesFound)) {
                    // The current index exists in the table, do something here :)
                }
            }
        }
    );
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all keys details of a specific table

```
$keys = DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW KEYS from users'));

foreach($keys as $item)
{
   echo $item->Key_name;
}
```

If you don't know the unique key name but know the **table** and the **column** name then here is a example code.

```
$keys = DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW KEYS from users'));

foreach($keys as $item)
   {
       if($item->Column_name == 'email')
       {
           Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) use($item) {
               $table->dropUnique($item->Key_name);
           });
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

All solution listed here are probably OK, but apparently most recent versions of Laravel don't support their syntax anymore, I'm always getting this exception:

```
PDO::prepare(): Argument #1 ($query) must be of type string, Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Expression`
```

I'm on Laravel 10.x-dev (yeah, is not a stable version, but it's not a problem in this case).

A little research lead me to this answer: [get all indexed column names from one specific table in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65286796/get-all-indexed-column-names-from-one-specific-table-in-laravel)

Basically `DB::raw()` must be removed, you can run the SQL directly inside the `select` method.

In case you will need it, I wrote a little function to check if one or more columns have an index, and if yes, ensures that all columns are linked to the same index (multicolumn index):

```php
public function tableHasIndexes(string $tableName, ...$columns): ?array
{
    $tableKeys = DB::select("SHOW KEYS FROM $tableName");

    if (empty($indexes = Arr::except($tableKeys, 'PRIMARY'))) {
        return null; // nessun index tanne la primary key :/
    }

    $matches = [];
    foreach ( $indexes as $index ) {
        if (in_array($index->Column_name, $columns)) {
            $matches[] = $index->Key_name;
        }
    }

    if (( $n_match = count($matches) ) !== ( $n_cols = count($columns) )) {
        Log::warning("Only $n_match over $n_cols have an index!");
        return null;
    }

    if (( $n_values = count($values = array_unique($matches)) ) !== ( $single = 1 )) {
        Log::warning('Selected columns are linked to different indexes: ' . implode(', ', $values));
        return null;
    }

    return $values;
}
```

It's a bit concise, sorry for that :-)