# get all indexed column names from one specific table in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

**Laravel Version 6**

*index type index*

**picture**

[image]

*I try to make search for model like below ...*

```
  Table::where($indexedColumn,'like','%'.$search.'%')->get();
```

Comment: DB::select('SHOW INDEX FROM table FROM database;')->get();

Comment: @TechSpot are you tried it ?

Comment: send an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use query builder of Laravel to get back the index columns of a specific table.
run anyway

> composer update

Here a simple example:

```
$data = DB::select('SHOW INDEX FROM table;');
$array = [];
foreach($data as $key =>  $item){ 
      $array[] = $item->Column_name; // <--- check column name 
}
dd($array);
```

Comment: it's giving me collection.. but  I try to retrieve column name.. I am failed .. also `$data` not loop.. also I tried to convert `toArray()` & `response()->json($data);`.. it's does not help me.. did you retrieve  column name

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: i am try to retrieve  indexed column names from one specific table in laravel ...what is my question..

Comment: @Tech Spot would you resolve the problem ?

Comment: @noor, well, i've already answered you. Did you try? :)

Comment: @Tech Spot i try it... i am failed to retrieve all index column names ..  i can not access column name . that was my very first comment on your answer.. would you give example how can i retrieve all column name

Comment: sorry for bothering you.. yesterday I tried it like : `$array = [];foreach($data as $key =>  $item){ $array[] = $item->Column_name;}dd($array);`.. after update composer today it's working find.. thanks for the ans ): ...

Comment: i will be happy  if you complete the answer ... that means put my code into the answer  and suggest to update composer.. so that future reader easily can get help...