# Simple SQL UPDATE Query slows down connection by 5-10 seconds

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using a simple `UPDATE` query in my MySQL Server.

Normally, the `SELECT` Queries I am using are returning results in about in instant. However, after performing the `UPDATE` query once, the entire connection starts slowing down and from that moment on it takes about 5-10 seconds to load the results of the `SELECT` queries.

```
$time = time();
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

if( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare( "UPDATE users SET last_online = ? WHERE username = ?" ) )
{
    $stmt->bind_param( 'is', $time, $_POST['username'] );
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
```

Any ideas why this could be slowing down the connection?

P.S.: It also slows down connections of other users.

P.P.S: This update is executed once per 13 minutes per user.

**Edit**

The slowdown happens when executed directly from MySQL too.

Comment: are the connections being released? Usually for updates or inserts one would use 'rw' connection and for select statements, one would use 'ro' connections and thus would not affect each other much

Comment: I would also check your indexing. I have seen this many times where a system is slowed substantially because of missing indexes on the proper columns.

Comment: You can enable slow query logging and check the logs.

Comment: And make sure there is NO index on `last_online`.

Comment: @SKY The connections are closed. @ckimbrell I changed the query to use `id` which is the primary key. Still 3-4 seconds delay. Without using this query there is almost no delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. One of the `SELECT` queries triggered another table in combination with the `users` table. That table contained massive data and used an `ORDER BY .. DESC` statement which was expensive. The problem is resolved now.

Maybe it had to update cache every time the `UPDATE` query was performed.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you do not have an index on `username`.  Then the query would require a full table scan, slowing things down.  You can create such an index by doing:

```
create index idx_users_username on users(username);
```

Comment: A way to check if index exists: [How do I check if index exists on a table field in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/q/127156/4577762)

Comment: `#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'username' used in key specification without a key length `

Comment: I changed the query to use `id` which is the primary key. Still 3-4 seconds delay. Without using this query there is almost no delay.

Comment: Do you have triggers on the table?

Comment: @Gordon: What do you mean by triggers? The problem is solved by the way. Thank you.

Comment: @Z0q . . . Triggers are additional code that is run when data is inserted/updated/deleted in a table.